# TCP segments with HTTP data

Tags: parsing, http, tcp

I'm implementing a http parser; As indicator of http data I'm searching for 'HTTP/1.? CRLF' in the stream. TCP layer may cut the application-provided buffer into chunks suitable for transferring over network. Is it possible to have http data (e.g. GET http://www.google.com/index.html HTTP/1.1 CRLF) NOT following immediately after TCP header? Also, is it possible to have, for example 'GET ..' query split across TCP segments?

Thanks.

Mark

Comment: Are you implementing an HTTP parser or a TCP/IP stack?

Comment: Is you parser low level? If not, simply use tshark for Linux or WinPcap for Windows.

Comment: What do you mean by *HTTP parser*?

Comment: @NPE, it's http parser.

Comment: @MattH, by http parser I mean piece of software capable to look up through the stream for protocol specific commands, tokens etc.

Comment: @KBart, it is a low level parser implemented on network processor using its assembler-like language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to have http data (e.g. GET http://www.google.com/index.html HTTP/1.1 CRLF) NOT following immediately after TCP header?

Possible yes. [HTTP Pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) makes it possible to have multiple requests in a single segment.

> Also, is it possible to have, for example 'GET ..' query split across TCP segments?

Yes. The request size can be bigger than the segment size. Additionally fragmentation of the TCP segment can occur at the IP layer.

This would be an uncommon natural occurrence, but could be part of intentional evasion.

The only way to be sure is to re-assemble the stream, however this is expensive in terms of processing and memory. If you care that much you may be better off using a transparent HTTP proxy.

Answer (score 3):

With TCP you need to basically assume that the segmentation can occur anyplace. You have to consider this while designing you parsing stack. You can't read one segment and assume that you have sufficient to read something. So the sensible way, is to view TCP as a stream and put it below your lexer. You just need accommodate for the fact that a call into the parser/lexer may take a bit longer or fault.

Comment: thanks for comment. So it is possible to have "GET http://www.google.com/index.html HTTP/1.1 CRLF" cut in three pieces: "GET http:", "//www.google.com", "/index.html HTTP/1.1 CRLF" and be sent in three different TCP segments?

Comment: It is improbably that you would get it that way, because segmentation is something around 512 - 1024 bytes. But in theory you could get one byte (char) per packet. On odd networks it may be possible to get `GE` `T google` `.` `c` `om` ... you get the picture.